# How to mirror a Matrix3D?

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d

I want to mirror my drawing.

I need to mirror my Matrix3D for this i think... But I don't have a clue to do this.

I tried like this:

```
  var transformation = sceneCamera.TransformationMatrix;
  var invertedTransformation = transformation;
  invertedTransformation.Invert();

  var trans = Transform3D.Identity.Value * transformation * invertedTransformation;
```

But this doesn't work.

As you see in the image the drawing in the report has to be mirrored.

**Thanks in advance!**

[image]

Comment: Mirroring in 3D can be done on any axis, do you want to invert the X coordinates for example? Then multiply by a scaling matrix which has an x-scale of -1.0, and y, z scale of 1.0. (That is, "mirroring" is a scaling, not an inversion.)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer with a code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "mirror" the model you can either mirror the camera transformation, or mirror the objects transformation. Mirroring in the camera will give the effect of mirroring the picture. Mirroring the model will mirror the object in the world, regardless of where you look at it from.

To mirror the camera in the x-direction, multiply the camera transform by a matrix that has a -1 x component and 1 for the other scalings. You may have to offset the camera since the mirroring may have moved the object out of view, depending on how the camera transform was set up to begin with.

```
var cameraTrans = sceneCamera.TransformationMatrix;
cameraTrans.Scale(new Vector3D(-1, 1, 1));
```